# My API is very slow, it has response times of 2000ms+

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webapi

When I make a call on an API with this program.cs the response will take at least 2000ms but why ?

Here is my Program.cs and what I've changed:

```
public readonly static string[] URLS = new string[] { "http://0.0.0.0:5250", "https://0.0.0.0:5251" };
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
  // Add services to the container.
  builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
  builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
  builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
     
#region this is what I added to the template:
     builder.WebHost.UseKestrel();
     builder.WebHost.UseUrls(URLS);
#endregion 

  var app = builder.Build();

  // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.MapControllers();
  app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the URLS from (avg. responsetime >2000ms):

```
public readonly static string[] URLS = new string[] { "http://0.0.0.0:5250", "https://0.0.0.0:5251" };
```

to this (avg. responsetime 30-50ms):

```
public readonly static string[] URLS = new string[] { "http://*:5250", "https://*:5251" };
```